# Javascript split function creates empty element if separator found

Tags: javascript, string, split

My first question on Stack :)

I wonder why the following statement :

```
'5+'.split('+')
```

will return an array of length 2 with `['5', '']`

There is nothing after the '+' symbol. Basically, everytime Javascript found the separator in a string, if the separator is found multiple time, he will create empty elements :

```
'5+++'.split('+')
['5', '', '', '']
```

I was expecting `['5']` for the 1 exemple.

Comment: nothing is the rest to the end of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're splitting `'5+'` with `+` as the separator, then returning two substrings (`'5'` and an empty string) is the correct result because that is what's on either side of the separator. If it had returned a list containing only one element and you had tried to `join` the list back together into the original string, you would get the wrong result.

```js
var elements = ['5'];

console.log(elements.join('+'));
```

But joining the result of split does give back the original string.

```js
var elements = '5+'.split('+');

console.log(elements);
console.log(elements.join('+'));
```